# Why does my Bluetooth headset stop my internet-using programs from working?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

On my Windows 10 enabled laptop, I was able to use my Bluetooth headset just fine yesterday, when it was fresh out of the package. Now today, I've noticed that whenever I connect the headset to my computer, it stops all my other internet using programs - like Skype, Pandora, Chrome, etc. - from working properly.

Why is this? Am I doing something wrong, or is my internet just bad? This Time Warner has been notorious for being bad.

Note: This seems to be connected to whenever I try to connect the Bluetooth feature using the "connect" menu in Windows 10. It always comes back with "couldn't connect"

EDIT: I tried connecting right as the computer started up, and the internet dropped out. This has to be a Bluetooth problem, right?

Comment: Can you be more specific with what's wrong with these programs? Headset model could be helpful too.

Comment: Some devices have known issues using Bluetooth and WiFi simultaneously... Can you be more specific about what make/model laptop and headset? Did this work properly on previous Windows version?

Comment: It's the MDR-ZX770DC. The most I know about my computer's model is that it's a Dell laptop with quad-core AMD with Raedon graphics. I can post more details later

Comment: Follow-up: It's actually an HP. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I would have rather put this as a comment (don't have the rep). Please post details about your system, such as motherboard, WiFi/Bluetooth adapter hardware, installed drivers, etc. Does Ethernet still work, just not WiFi?

I used to have the same problem as you. My laptop has an [Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/intel-wi-fi-products/intel-centrino-wireless-n-2000-series/intel-centrino-wireless-n-2230-single-band.html) WiFi/Bluetooth adapter. Windows did not automatically install the correct drivers, so whenever I would turn on Bluetooth, my wireless adapter (WiFi and Bluetooth) would stop working until a reboot. The driver wouldn't "crash", just the internet wouldn't work.

First I installed the regular Intel PROSet driver (probably [this](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25833) one). When this didn't fix the issue, I then installed the [Intel PROSet/Wireless Software for Bluetooth® technology for Windows 10 64-bit](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25206/Intel-PROSet-Wireless-Software-for-Bluetooth-technology-for-Windows-10-64-bit-JP-) driver, which fixed the issue.

**EDIT:** Because I still can't comment on your question... There's no way anyone can answer your question without knowing more about your computer. Knowing that it's an HP laptop tells us nothing. You'll need to run the "System Information" program (type that into Cortana), click "Components", then "Network", then "Adapter". In the right panel, click on any item, then click "Edit>Select All". Then "Edit>Copy". Paste the results into your question. Delete any personally identifying information such as the IP addresses if you wish.

Comment: @RecoveryOne I added details about finding system information.